# Time of delete and insert action on table in MySQL database

Tags: mysql, sql, mysql-workbench

In SQL is there any way to find the last time a table had an insert and  delete statement performed on it? I tried

```
select update_time from information.schema.tables where table_num="tablename";
```

but that did not work. I am also trying to look at deletions and insertions specifically. I am also working in MySQL Workbench.

Comment: What does not work with that?

Comment: There's a period between `information` and `schema`. Should be an underscore. I mean: `information_schema.tables`. Is that it?

Comment: You were right, it should have the underscore instead of a period. However, it just returned null for me.